# Null type-guard by fn overloading

Tags: typescript

Can I do an overload in Typescript for `cb` which says if `Error` is null then `Id` must be defined or if `Error` defined then `Id` must be null?

```
    function passId(cb: (err: Error, id: null) => void): any
    function passId(cb: (err: null, id: number) => void): any
    function passId(cb: (err: Error | null, id: number | null) => void){
        // implementation ...
     }


    // usage: if error defined and the fn returns 
    // then it means because of the type definition number must be defined.

   const foo = () => {
      if(err){
        return
      }

      // id must be defined by here..
      let a: number = id
   }
```

Comment: What's with the 3rd variant?

Comment: The third variant would be the function implementation.

Comment: Where that `if(err)` code supposed to be?

Comment: I'm updating the example.

Comment: Please consider editing this code to constitute a [mcve] which can be dropped into an IDE to demonstrate the issue.  As it stands I'm not sure where the `err` in  `if (err)` is coming from, and how it has anything to do with `passId()`.  Neither `err` nor `id` seem to be in scope.

Comment: It's hard to see how this makes sense; function types are contravariant in their parameter types, so if `cb` is either a function that takes `Error`, or a function that takes `null`, then whichever of those you pass it you can't be sure that `cb` doesn't take the other option instead. There is no argument type which is definitely accepted by `cb`.

Comment: I'll be more precise: that's an awful lot of `any`. It's really hard to tell what you actually want and what any of this is supposed to be doing.

Comment: Maybe [this](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#code/MYewdgzgLgBAZiEMC8MAUA6LBTATrgSQBMAuGAbQFF8RcAaGMAVwBsWBdGAHwubYeYBbAEZ52AShQA+GAG8AUDBgBLOOjyEi5AAwS5ipTFzYoTXGAMBfAyxMwAhmSGjcKGBuLkAjO3nWYQA) is what you want?  But it's really hard to tell.  Anyway I'm signing off here; good luck!